# Touching segments

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, graph-theory, overlapping

Can anyone please suggest me algorithm for this.

You are given starting and the ending points of N segments over the x-axis. 
How many of these segments can be touched, even on their edges, by exactly two lines perpendicular to them?

Sample Input :

```
3
5
2 3
1 3
1 5
3 4
4 5
5
1 2
1 3
2 3
1 4
1 5
3
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Sample Output :

```
Case 1: 5
Case 2: 5
Case 3: 2
```

Explanation :

- Case 1: We will draw two lines (parallel to Y-axis) crossing X-axis at point 2 and 4. These two lines will touch all the five segments.
- Case 2: We can touch all the points even with one line crossing X-axis at 2.
- Case 3: It is not possible to touch more than two points in this case.

Constraints:

```
1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5
0 ≤ a < b ≤ 10^9
```

Comment: `by exactly two lines perpendicular to them` ? so these two lines will parallel to the y axis, do they need to cross the x axis in integer point?

Comment: @PhamTrung , yes it has to be either cross or touched.

Comment: In **integer** point? or any point ?

Comment: No, only integer points.

Comment: I would start by looking data structures like segment trees or interval trees, and using the following hint : Each of those 2 perpendicular lines must pass through at least one of the segment's edge.

Comment: Also consider dynamic programming: suppose you already solved the problem when there is n segments. What happens when you add a new segment ?

Comment: Here is another idea : construct a graph G. The vertices of G are the segments. There is an edge (I, J) in G iff the segments I and J overlap. From this you can deduce some intersting facts: G is complete iff all edges overlap, ... So I think that basically you need to look for the 2 maximum complete subgraphs

Comment: This sounds typically like an ACM or TopCoder problem. Do you have the original URL so I can submit a solution ? :)

Comment: That's a pretty trivial to solve problem. You only have to consider what happens at critical points (those that start or end a segment) ordered from left to right.

Comment: @salva That's right, and then ? I don't think it's so trivial. You cannot bruteforce, otherwise the complexity will be too big

Comment: @Brainless: all you have to do is to consider at every critical point how many segments touch it. Then get the two which are touched the most and draw the lines there.

Comment: @salva No, the 2 points which are touched the most aren't necessarily the optimal ones. Consider for example : (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9). Your idea wold return 5 and 6 with 4 segments touched, but one of the correct answer would be 1 and 5.

Comment: @Brainless: ah, I had not understood the problem correctly!

Answer (score 3):

Let assume that we have a data structure that supports the following operations efficiently:

1. Add a segment.
2. Delete a segment.
3. Return the maximum number of segments that cover one point(that is, the "best" point).

If have such a structure, we can get use the initial problem efficiently in the following manner:

1. Let's create an array of events(one event for the start of each segment and one for the end) and sort by the x-coordinate.
2. Add all segments to the magical data structure.
3. Iterate over all events and do the following: when a segment start, add  one to the number of currently covered segments and remove it from that data structure. When a segment ends, subtract one from the number of currently covered segment and add this segment to the magical data structure. After each event, update the answer with the value of the number of currently covered segments(it shows how many segments are covered by the point which corresponds to the current event) plus the maximum returned by the data structure described above(it shows how we can choose another point in the best possible way).

If this data structure can perform all given operations in `O(log n)`, then we have an `O(n log n)` solution(we sort the events and make one pass over the sorted array making a constant number of queries to this data structure for each event).

So how can we implement this data structure? Well, a segment tree works fine here. Adding a segment is adding one to a specific range. Removing a segment is subtracting one from all elements in a specific range. Get ting the maximum is just a standard maximum operation on a segment tree. So we need a segment tree that supports two operations: add a constant to a range and get maximum for the entire tree. It can be done in `O(log n)` time per query.

One more note: a standard segment tree requires coordinates to be small. We may assume that they never exceed `2 * n`(if it is not the case, we can compress them).

Comment: Isn't based on line-sweep-algorithm?

Comment: @VikasGupta Yes, it is.

Comment: @kraskevich can please tell why this approach fails for some test cases: 1. do cordinate compression                                                                                        2. then for every line segment (x1,x2) .. int array[x1]+=1 and int arr[x2+1]-=1                                                                                                              3. for(i =1 to n) array[i]+=array[i-1].                                                                 4. find the max point and the remove all segment that intersect with this point and then repeat to get the second point

Comment: @Ritesh This algorithm is wrong. Taking the first maximum, removing covered segments and taking the maximum once again is not the same thing as taking two points which maximize the sum. Counterexample: {(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 4)}. If we pick 2 at the first step, we get a wrong answer(and it is one of the maximums).

Answer (score 1):

An `O(N*max(logN, M))` solution, where M is the medium segment size, implemented in Common Lisp: [touching-segments.lisp](https://github.com/salva/simplering/blob/master/touching-segments/touching-segments.lisp).

The idea is to first calculate from left to right at every interesting point the number of segments that would be touched by a line there (`open-left-to-right` on the lisp code). Cost: O(NlogN)

Then, from right to left it calculates, again at every interesting point `P`, the best location for a line considering segments **fully to the right** of `P` (`open-right-to-left` on the lisp code). Cost O(N*max(logN, M))

Then it is just a matter of looking for the point where the sum of both values tops. Cost O(N).

The code is barely tested and may contain bugs. Also, I have not bothered to handle edge cases as when the number of segments is zero.

Answer (score 1):

1. The problem can be solved in **O(Nlog(N))** time per test case.
2. Observe that there is an optimal placement of two vertical lines each of  which go through some segment endpoints
3. Compress segments' coordinates. More info at What is [coordinate compression](http://www.quora.com/What-is-coordinate-compression)?
4. Build a sorted set of segment endpoints **X**
5. Sort segments **[a_i,b_i]** by **a_i**
6. Let Q be a priority queue which stores right endpoints of segments processed so far
7. Let T be a max interval tree built over x-coordinates. Some useful reading at[What are some sources (books, etc.) from where I can learn about Interval, Segment, Range trees?](http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-sources-books-etc-from-where-I-can-learn-about-Interval-Segment-Range-trees)
8. For each segment make **[a_i,b_i]**-range **increment-by-1 query to T**. It allows to find maximum number of segments covering **some x in [a,b]**
9. Iterate over elements x of X. For each x process segments (not already processed) with **x >= a_i.** The processing includes pushing **b_i to Q** and making  **[a_i,b_i]-range increment-by-(-1) query to T**. After removing from Q all elements < x, A= Q.size is equal to number of segments covering x. **B = T.rmq(x + 1, M)** returns maximum number of segments that do not cover x and cover some fixed y > x. **A + B is a candidate for an answer.**

Source:
http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-intended-solutions-for-the-Touching-segments-and-the-Smallest-String-and-Regex-problems-from-the-Cisco-Software-Challenge-held-on-Hackerrank