# Count horizontal line segments cut by two vertical lines

Tags: algorithm

Given N horizontal line segments with there starting and ending points (Namely A and B) with no restriction on overlapping criteria. Which means we have line segment from (A,0) to (B,0) . Now we can draw two vertical lines passing through these lines. We need to find the maximum line segments that these two lines can cross.
(If a vertical line touches any horizontal line segment it is also to be counted)

Example : Let us suppose we have 5 line segments :

```
2 3
1 3
1 5
3 4
4 5
```

Then We will draw two lines (parallel to Y-axis) crossing X-axis at point 2 and 4. These two lines will touch all the five segments.So answer for this is 5.

But lets suppose we have 3 line segments :

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Then answer is 2 as It is not possible to touch more than two points in this case.

How to solve this problem ? Please help.

Note 1≤N≤10^5 and  0 ≤ A < B ≤ 10^9

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of hints for this problem.

### Hint 1

Set a variable count to 0.

Now sort the start and end events and loop over the events in increasing order.

If you see a start event, increase the count by 1.

If you see an end event, decrease the count by 1.

At each step in the algorithm, count gives the number of intervals overlapping the current x position.

### Hint 2

The above hint shows how to find a single line overlapping the most intervals.

However, we want to find 2 lines.  So what we need to do is to be able to find a second line that crosses the most number of intervals - not including the intervals touching the first line.

What you can do is use a segment tree with lazy propagation (C++ code [here](https://gist.github.com/shobhit6993/7088061)).  This allows you to add intervals / query the largest value in time O(logn).

You can combine this with Hint 1 by only adding intervals to the segment tree when you see end events.

In pseudocode the complete algorithm will be:

```
For each event in sorted order:
   if event.type==start: count += 1
   if event.type==end: count -= 1 and update segment tree to add 1 to all points in range event.start to event.end
   current_value = count + maximum value in segment tree
   best_value = max(best_value,current_value)
```

The overall complexity will be O(nlogn) for the initial sort, plus O(nlogn) for the scan to find the best pair of lines.

Comment: Can you explain how are you sorting events ? Am not getting that part. Segment tree i got pretty well but not his For each event in sorted order:
   if event.type==start: count += 1
   if event.type==end: count -= 1

Comment: Are there two seperate arrays for start and end ?

Comment: What is event.type in this whole ??

Comment: I just spotted that kraskevich posted an answer to the same question at the same time as I wrote this.  It uses the same approach but has more explanation so I recommend that you look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555741/touching-segments)

Comment: @ Peter de Rivaz Initially array for segment tree has all zeroes right ?

Comment: In my solution that is correct, the segment tree starts empty.